# Basic PHP Echo Issue

Tags: php

New to PHP, I tried looking this up on other stackoverflow threads as well as online, but it seems I've been doing everything right. I'm trying to understand why the 200 response I'm getting outputs the break literally (I'm seeing literal br tag). I just want a Your inquiry etc. to be on a new line.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }
        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "";
        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New Inquiry from $name";
        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank you.<br>Your inquiry has been received, and we will get back to you as soon as possible.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sry, I dont get what is what you're seeing and what is what you're supposed to see.

Comment: If your title is "Basic PHP Echo Issue" and you are posting an entire wall of code you probably haven't isolated / debugged the problem properly.

Comment: It's this specific line which is not rendering as HTML: echo "Thank you.<br>Your inquiry has been received, and we will get back to you as soon as possible.";

Comment: Are you calling this script via AJAX, or a simple form POST?

Comment: Either way, I can't reproduce your problem. That echo statement works fine for me. Maybe the browser is parsing the request wrong, is it expecting JSON back or something?

Comment: There's AJAX on submit, but the HTML has a post method and action. The action hits the script I posted. I saw here (http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_echo3) that br works in echo so am confused why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: No JSON is expected back. I'm going to call my host as maybe it's something wrong coming from their end.

Comment: Seems like something is escaping your tags.

Answer (score -1):

On this line:

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
```

Did you try with a value as `$recipient` ?
It is defined as empty 10 lines above.
I looked at your code and saw nothing else...

But THIS looks like a good reason for `mail()` to fail.
;)